# multiple loadbalancers in modjk configuration in Apache Webserver for JBoss Instance Load-balancing

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss, load-balancing, mod-jk

In most of the cases, we will have
1)only one worker defined of type 'lb' (Loadbalancer)
2)we will have multiple member workers (target application server instances defined)
3)We will map those target workers with defined load balancer with
the attribute worker..balance_workers= worker1,worker2

The following are the queries.

1)Is it possible to have multiple load balancers defined in the same modjk config file and have different set of target workers associated with those workers.

2) Is it possible to define the Load balancing mechanism at application level ( different lb factor approach for different kind of application ( having different application context but running on the same worker node).? If it is possible, how can we configure that?

3) Is there any way to set time out for those requests which may take longer time intervals to send response back?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you *can* have multiple workers but they'd obviously need to be uniquely named like:

```
JkMount /context1 worker1
JkMount /context2 worker2
```

Load-balancing factor is per worker, not per context but you could probably emulate what you want to do by setting up a worker for each context.

mod_jk has many different types of timeouts.  I *think* the one you want would be **reply_timeout**